# Download profile pictures from My sites into local folder?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I am working on download profile picture from my sites into local drive. I don't understand how to approach that concept. Please some one give an idea or code steps. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a web site...

How about:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
}
```

Courtesy of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992498/how-to-get-data-from-an-url-and-save-it-into-a-file-in-binary-in-c-net-without-t)